# generic type parameter that doesn't relate two or more values

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

The typescript handbook says that generic type parameters are for cases "where the types of the input relate to the type of the output, or where the types of two inputs are related in some way". It also says that you should not use a generic type parameter "that doesn’t relate two values. That’s always a red flag, because it means callers wanting to specify type arguments have to manually specify an extra type argument for no reason."

Today I wrote a function that will be called in the constructor of various classes; it returns a function that can be passed to methods of that class and the arguments those methods take, and calls that method with a timeout feature that will reject the promise they return if some amount of time passes. It looks like this:

```js
export function getTimer<ThisT>(thisArg: ThisT, ms: number) {
  const time = <T>(fn: (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>, ...args: any[]): Promise<T> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => reject(`Error: ${fn.name} timed out`), ms)
      try {
        resolve(await fn.bind(thisArg)(...args))
      } catch(err) {
        reject(err)
      } finally {
        clearTimeout(timer)
      }
    })
  }
  return time
}
```

In the constructor of a class, this line appears:

```js
this.time = getTimer(this, this.TIMEOUT)
```

And then various methods look like this:

```js
async getTokenInfo(token: string): Promise<TokenInfo> {
   return await this.time(this._getTokenInfo, token)
}
```

As you can see, the `getTimer` function takes a generic type parameter `ThisT`, which is supposed to be the type of the class that is creating the timer. You can also see that `ThisT` is not used anywhere else, so it doesn't "relate two values". I added that type parameter because I didn't want `thisArg` to be `any`; if it was `any`, then calling `fn.bind(thisArg)` would bind the function to an `any` value, and I would lose the type information of what `this` is (I think?). Plus, as I understand it, you should avoid `any` values when possible. If I've understood what's happening, creating `ThisT` generic type parameter allows the compiler to infer the type of `ThisT` according to what I actually pass as `thisArg`, and so when `fn` gets bound to `thisArg`, the compiler understands what I am binding it to.

So my question is, am I doing something wrong? I ask because this seems to be contrary to what the TS docs says generic type parameters are for.

Comment: Why do you think you need the `ThisT` generic parameter? There's no `this` type to lose, because `this` is not used in your return type of `getTimer`. Your function works fine without it. https://tsplay.dev/w1yJKw So what problem did you have before you added the `ThisT` generic parameter?

Comment: @AlexWayne hmm yeah it seems to work the same. It's just odd, I have `strictBindCallApply` turned on, and I thought that meant that the compiler actually checks what you are binding to to make sure you are calling the found function with the proper arguments. What I wanted was for the compiler to check that I was passing the proper arguments but neither my way nor your way seems to do that. But you're right it works without ThisT

Answer (score 0):

You were definitely on the right track. There were a few issues in the `args` destructing and the `async/await` setup within your `promise`.

Here you can find the code.

```
function getTimer<T>(timeout: number) {
  const time = (
    fn: (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>,
    args: any
  ) => {
    const promise = new Promise(async (resolve: (value: Awaited<T>) => void, reject) => {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => reject(`Error ${fn.name} timed out`), timeout)
      try {
        const data = await fn(...args)
        resolve(data)
      } catch(err) {
        reject(err)
      } finally {
        clearTimeout(timer)
      }
    })
    return promise
  }
  return time
}

type TokenInfo = {
  token: string
  info: string
}

class MyClass {
  private TIMEOUT: number
  private _time: <T>(fn: (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>, ...args: any[]) => Promise<T>

  constructor(accepted_timeout: number) {
    this.TIMEOUT = accepted_timeout
    this._time = getTimer(this.TIMEOUT)
  }

  get time() { return this._time }

  private _getTokenInfo(token: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve: (value: TokenInfo) => void) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const tokenInfo: TokenInfo = { token, info: 'info_about_your_token' }
        resolve(tokenInfo)
      }, 500)
    })
  }

  async getTokenInfo(token: string) {
    return await this.time(this._getTokenInfo.bind(this), token)
  }

}

new MyClass(300) // short timeout 
  .getTokenInfo('my_secret_token')
  .then(tokenInfo => {
    console.log(tokenInfo) // ... no response timed out ...
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('ERROR', error) // "ERROR",  "Error _getTokenInfo timed out" 
  })
  
new MyClass(1000) // long timeout
  .getTokenInfo('my_secret_token')
  .then(tokenInfo => {
    console.log(tokenInfo) // { "token": "my_secret_token", "info": "info_about_your_token" } 
  })
```

Or instead of calling the function within the `getTimer`, you can call it within your class function, which will return a `promise`. Within the `getTimer` you just `await` the data and resolve. Destructing the `args` isn't necessary anymore, as well as the binding to `this`. For logging purposes you just provide the name of the function as a string. If that's not important, you can also omit that property.

```
function getTimer<T>(timeout: number) {
  const time = (
    name: string,
    promise: Promise<T>,
  ) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve: (value: Awaited<T>) => void, reject) => {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => reject(`Error ${name} timed out`), timeout)
      try {
        const data = await promise
        resolve(data)
      } catch(err) {
        reject(err)
      } finally {
        clearTimeout(timer)
      }
    })
  }
  return time
}

type TokenInfo = {
  token: string
  info: string
}

class MyClass {
  private TIMEOUT: number
  private _time: <T>(name: string, promise: Promise<T>) => Promise<Awaited<T>>

  constructor(accepted_timeout: number) {
    this.TIMEOUT = accepted_timeout
    this._time = getTimer(this.TIMEOUT)
  }

  get time() { return this._time }

  private _getTokenInfo(token: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve: (value: TokenInfo) => void) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const tokenInfo: TokenInfo = { token, info: 'info_about_your_token' }
        resolve(tokenInfo)
      }, 500)
    })
  }

  async getTokenInfo(token: string) {
    return await this.time(this.getTokenInfo.name, this._getTokenInfo(token))
  }

}

new MyClass(300) // short timeout 
  .getTokenInfo('my_secret_token')
  .then(tokenInfo => {
    console.log(tokenInfo) // ... no response timed out ...
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('ERROR', error) // "ERROR",  "Error getTokenInfo timed out" 
  })

new MyClass(1000) // long timeout
  .getTokenInfo('my_secret_token')
  .then(tokenInfo => {
    console.log(tokenInfo) // { "token": "my_secret_token", "info": "info_about_your_token" } 
  })
```

Comment: Did not work. When I don't bind to `this`, functions like _getTokenInfo are unable to access other properties of the class they are members of. https://tsplay.dev/WYkA3N

Comment: Ok, it that case you need the binding, but do the binding within your class function. like `return await this.time(this._getTokenInfo.bind(this), token)`. For the second solution, you don't need the binding.